# Link username and password in Python

Tags: python, authentication

Newbie to python and just trying to get a grasp of things.

Ive written a practice piece of code where a user is asked to enter their username and password from this mock database. My question is how do I get the username to correlate with the password for any given user? So user "amy" password would be "apple". Do I need just a single variable setup as a dictionary instead or something along those lines?

```
list= ["amy", "chris", "jake"]

password = ["apple", "orange", "date"]

login = ("")

counter = 0

attempts = 5

out_of_attempts = False

while login not in list and not (out_of_attempts):

    if counter < attempts:
        login = input ("enter username: ")
        counter += 1
    else:
        out_of_attempts = True

if out_of_attempts:

        print ("Sorry login limit exceeded please try again later")

else:
        pass
        
while login not in password and not (out_of_attempts):

        if counter < attempts:
            login = input ("now password please: ")
            counter += 1
        else:
            out_of_attempts = True
    
            
if out_of_attempts:

        print ("sorry password limit exceeded, try again later")

else:
    print ("thank you please wait")
```

Comment: Python *has* dictionary objects, so `credentials = {'Amy': 'apple'}` 'maps' the word 'Amy' to the password 'apple'.

Comment: You would probably want to create a User class and have it store the credentials in a more real world scenario.

Comment: @SnowGroomer In addition, in a 'real-world' scenario the password would never be hard-coded by the server, nor would it exist in plaintext anywhere (hopefully).

Comment: Thank you very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, a dictionary setup will be better:

```
auth = {'amy': 'apple'....
```

And so on. Code modification would not be so hard. To get the password of an user (use this to set too)

```
auth[login]
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent 'mapping' of your usernames/passwords can be done as:

```py
credentials = {
    'amy': 'apple',
    'chris': 'orange',
    'jake': 'date',
}
```

These allow you to quick 'checks' such as: `username in credentials` (return `True` or `False`) to see if a username has a password; get the password for a given username with `credentials[username]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple *slightly more secure* way that allows you to store more than just passwords

```
import hashlib

db = {}

hash = lambda x: hashlib.md5(x.encode()).hexdigest()

def register(user, password, mail):
    db[user] = {"password": hash(password), "mail": mail}

def login(user, password):
    if db[user]["password"] == hash(password):
        print("success!")
    else:
        print("fail")

register("ironkey", "password123", "example@example.com")

login("ironkey", "password")
login("ironkey", "password123")

# get credentials for the user ironkey
print(db["ironkey"])
```

```
fail
success!
{'password': '482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38', 'mail': 'example@example.com'}
```